# What is the easiest way to make a C++ program crash?

Tags: c++, crash

I'm trying to make a Python program that interfaces with a different crashy process (that's out of my hands). Unfortunately the program I'm interfacing with doesn't even crash reliably! So I want to make a quick C++ program that crashes on purpose but I don't actually know the best and shortest way to do that, does anyone know what to put between my:

```
int main() {
    crashyCodeGoesHere();
}
```

to make my C++ program crash reliably

Comment: you can use inline assembly to attempt to execute privleged instructions: `asm { cli; };`

Comment: @aitchnyu I think there is a difference in the usability of the answers to each question. (FYI: I've not voted anything for either question)

Comment: any comment of throwing exception while one already propogates??
plz chk my answer below anc comment

Comment: Redis uses the following `*((char*)-1) = 'x';` code to induce a crash in order to debug read more in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20844979/1708801)

Comment: I found this question searching for a test case for a crash reporting system. I needed to force a crash during normal runtime to invoke the crash reporter and stack dump sending. Thanks!

Comment: This should always crash on all systems. `int *p = (int *)-1; *p = 1;`. This is because memory address 2^64 - 1 does not exist on any system, at least, not now (assuming pointer is 8 bytes long).

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The `abort()` function is probably your best bet. It's part of the C standard library, and is defined as "causing abnormal program termination" (e.g, a fatal error or crash).

Comment: Note that a crash through `abort()` doesn't call any destructors or `atexit` functions, though that will likely not matter here.

Comment: @Xeo: If it did call destructors and `atexit`s, it wouldn't be a crash now would it?

Comment: Since `abort()` is the correct answer, then should 'exit(-1);` be acceptable?

Comment: No, since it doesn't cause a crash, merely reports something couldn't be done.

Comment: Windows. GCC-5.4.0. Exit code: 3. No error message box. Console message: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.".

Comment: Will calling `abort()` trigger things like crashpad? My reason for wanting to crash my application is to ensure that crash-reporting is working correctly.

Answer (score 128):

Try:

```
raise(SIGSEGV);  // simulates a standard crash when access invalid memory
                 // ie anything that can go wrong with pointers.
```

Found in:

```
#include <signal.h>
```

Comment: It's more than just implementation-defined -- the signal can be caught with `signal()`. Most sane applications don't, though.

Comment: It will crash in exactly the same way as a normal SIGSEGV within the application (which is the way most applications crash). It is well defined what it does (by default it exits the application and generates a core file). Yes you can set a handler, but if you have one don't you want to test that in the same way!!

Comment: +1 for `raise()`. This lets you test for a ton of different types of exceptions by just changing the argument.

Comment: favorite solution, however it is platform dependent .

Comment: @NadimFarhat: In what way. A signal is a signal on all platforms.

Comment: Windows. GCC-5.4.0. Exit code: 3. No error message box. No console message.

Answer (score 76):

Dividing by zero will crash the application:

```
int main()
{
    return 1 / 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on how clever your compiler is this will be caught at compile time.  I know that visual studio 2008 won't compile this for c++ or c#.

Comment: Since this code is subject to constant folding it will not be even be compiled successfully so we cannot here say it can crash anything since you'll not have executable to run.

Comment: I've compiled and run it, do you want me to sand you the .exe ?

Comment: In release configuration in Visual Studio recent versions like 2010, it will run without problem. I guess it's some optimization.

Comment: iirc it does not crashes on arm

Comment: This is undefined behavior and is not guaranteed to crash. Often compilers assume undefined behavior to be unreachable. This can lead to the body of `main` being entirely deleted including the `ret` instruction. Execution might just fall into the following function.

Comment: My compiler didn't allow 1/0, I had to do this: int x=0; 1/x;

Comment: Windows. GCC-5.4.0. Exit code: -1073741676. No console message. Pops up error message box: "Application Error. 
The exception Integer division by zero. (0x0000094) occurred in the application at location 0x001a3fe2.

Click on OK to terminate the program."

Comment: Dividing by 0 is UB... it MIGHT crash the application.  It might also just return 5.

Comment: Tested on Visual Studio 2013: it generates error at compiling time: error C2124: divide or mod by zero

Answer (score 70):

```
*((unsigned int*)0) = 0xDEAD;
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to crash.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer: no, it's not *guaranteed*. But which sane OS *doesn't* stop an application that tries to access memory at address 0?

Comment: "But which sane OS doesn't stop an application that tries to access memory at address 0?" -- That isn't really what you want to ask, but I'll answer anyway.  In some computers there is RAM at address 0, and it is perfectly meaningful for a program to store a value there.  A more meaningful question would be "Which OS doesn't stop an application that access memory at the address that a C++ implementation reserved for a null pointer?"  In that case I don't know of any.  But the original program is about the C++ language not about OSes.

Comment: Its undefined behavior. It is perfectly OK for this to do nothing. A machine that will not crash: Anything running a Z80 series processor (I assume (my Z80a does nothing)).

Comment: Although this isn't *guaranteed* to crash, it is one of the most common *kinds* of crash in C++. So if you want to simulate a crash, this is an "authentic" way to do it :)

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown: Accessing the zero address on machines that will actually crash generates a SIGSEGV signal. So much easier to just just raise(SIGSEGV). Thus you simulate the exact behavior in a way that is reproducible.

Comment: @Loki: You run python on your Z80-based system? I'm impressed; I didn't think you could address enough memory on an 8-bit system to do that…

Comment: @DonalFellows: No. What made you think python?

Comment: @Loki,  python is in the original question up the top.  given its running python, its likely to be running on a system with a MMU and if so, its most probable this will crash all the time.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: My original point holds. I just came up with one system off the top of my head. Assuming it will crash is a bad idea as what may crash on your PC does not mean it holds any further than that. A lot of people got hurt by assuming PC was the predominant architecture. There has been a huge shift in development recently and a lot of development has moved to mobile devices were there some assumptions no longer held. Who knows what/when the next architecture change will do. Relying on (or getting used to) undefined behavior working a particular way will just lead to bad things later.

Comment: @Loki, I think within the context of the question asked, this is ok.  The guy just wants a temporary method of crashing to bootstrap his python testing code.  This method is a common *real* crash that C++ systems do.   Other than abort, which is a non 'real' crash, there is no defined way of crashing, as almost by definitions, crashes are happen when you cross into the land of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Keith Nichola: I disagree. This question is going to be read by lots more people than the OP trying to work out how to cause a crash. We need to answer this taking these people into consideration.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Mac OS Classic would be one such OS (Mac OS X, of course, does stop the program).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: HPUX allows reads and writes to 0. And it's a recent enough OS that there are still people running it.

Comment: This will not compile if your compiler warning flags are overly zealous, and you sometimes don't have the power to change them.

Comment: That's UB. It doesn't depend on architecture only, the compiler can assume this code is never reached. `echo 'void crash(void) { *(unsigned *)0 = 0xdead; }' | clang -std=c99 -O2 -c -x c -` gives `<stdin>:1:20: warning: indirection of non-volatile null pointer will be deleted, not trap [-Wnull-dereference]` and suggests using either `__builtin_trap` or `*(volatile unsigned *)0`.

Comment: This is undefined behavior and is not guaranteed to crash. Often compilers assume undefined behavior to be unreachable. In that case at least this line is going to be deleted and other code might as well be.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Win95/98 lets user-space write the zero page (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13263976), where the IDT (interrupt descriptor table) resides.  Oh nvm, you said "sane", not "once widely used".

Comment: Many, many microcontrollers have data at location 0 that you are meant to write.

Answer (score 56):

Well, are we on *stack***overflow**, or not?

```
for (long long int i = 0; ++i; (&i)[i] = i);
```

(Not guaranteed to crash by any standards, but neither are any of the suggested answers including the accepted one since `SIGABRT` could have been caught anyway. In practice, this will crash everywhere.)

Comment: I can see that being funny on a system with non protected code pages and you overwrite your program with some code that is accidentally an infinite loop that does nothing. Highly highly highly highly unlikely but potentially possible.

Comment: @Loki: What if it just read from every 4000th byte?  Would that be less likely to crash?  Definitely less dangerous.

Comment: That crashing algorithm isn't O(1)!

Comment: @MooingDuck: I am just making a funny comment. Don't take it that seriously :-) But it would be interesting if somebody found a a sequence of instructions that did something funny.

Comment: @LokiAstari: you're absolutely right. I was thinking about `(&i)[i] += !i` instead, but I feared the compiler might be clever enough and want to optimise that out. :-)

Comment: Even if this *will* crash: will your colleagues understand it?

Comment: If there is no MMU it might be that this never crashes!!!!!

Answer (score 36):

```
 throw 42;
```

Just the answer... :)

Comment: Windows. GCC-5.4.0. Exit code: 3. No error message box. Console message: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.".

Answer (score 17):

`assert(false);` is pretty good too.

According to ISO/IEC 9899:1999 it is guaranteed to crash when NDEBUG is not defined:

> If NDEBUG is defined [...] the assert macro is defined simply as
>
> ```
> #define assert(ignore) ((void)0)
> ```
>
> The assert macro is redefined according to the current state of NDEBUG each time that  is included.
>
> [...]
>
> The assert macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; [...] if expression (which shall have a scalar type) is false [...]. It
>   then calls the abort function.

Comment: I vaguely remember VC 2005 behaving differently between debug and release with asserts?

Comment: @Tom `assert` is made equivalent to `((void)0)` in Release mode.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Dont see whats wrong with this - only if the define NDEBUG defined will is not crash? Dans answer was pretty fair IMHO.

Comment: @AdrianCornish I was only answering Tom Kerr's question, not saying this answer was wrong. I didn't downvote this answer.

Comment: @DanF: There is an explanation: assert is `((void)0)` if `NDEBUG` is defined (release mode), which does nothing.  So a release build _will not crash_!  The answer is even more wrong than it was before now that you quoted the spec.

Comment: I didn't quote it, someone else added that.

Comment: I don't know why he would do a "release" build of this test code.

Answer (score 12):

Since a crash is a symptom of invoking undefined behaviour, and since invoking undefined behaviour can lead to anything, including a crash, I don't think you want to really crash your program, but just have it drop into a debugger. The most portable way to do so is probably `abort()`.

While `raise(SIGABRT)` has the same effect, it is certainly more to write. Both ways however can be intercepted by installing a signal handler for `SIGABRT`. So depending on your situation, you might want/need to raise another signal. `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` or `SIGSEGV` might be the way to go, but they all can be intercepted.

When you can be unportable, your choices might be even broader, like using `SIGBUS` on linux.

Comment: I really doubt that he wants a debugger involved. He seems to want to test what happens when the caller of a crashing program gets a crash sent his way. Which is very reasonable.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is platform specific and depends on your goals. But here's the Mozilla Javascript crash function, which I think illustrates a lot of the challenges to making this work:

```
static JS_NEVER_INLINE void
CrashInJS()
{
    /*
     * We write 123 here so that the machine code for this function is
     * unique. Otherwise the linker, trying to be smart, might use the
     * same code for CrashInJS and for some other function. That
     * messes up the signature in minidumps.
     */

#if defined(WIN32)
    /*
     * We used to call DebugBreak() on Windows, but amazingly, it causes
     * the MSVS 2010 debugger not to be able to recover a call stack.
     */
    *((int *) NULL) = 123;
    exit(3);
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
    /*
     * On Mac OS X, Breakpad ignores signals. Only real Mach exceptions are
     * trapped.
     */
    *((int *) NULL) = 123;  /* To continue from here in GDB: "return" then "continue". */
    raise(SIGABRT);  /* In case above statement gets nixed by the optimizer. */
#else
    raise(SIGABRT);  /* To continue from here in GDB: "signal 0". */
#endif
}
```

Comment: You should totally drop that and use jQuery instead.

Comment: This is undefined behavior and is not guaranteed to crash. Often compilers assume undefined behavior to be unreachable. In that case at least the crashing line is going to be deleted and other code might be as well.

Answer (score 9):

The only flash I had is **abort() function**:

It aborts the process with an abnormal program termination.It generates the **SIGABRT signal**, which by default causes the program to terminate returning an unsuccessful termination error code to the host environment.The program is terminated **without executing destructors** for objects of automatic or static storage duration, and **without calling** any **atexit**( which is called by exit() before the program terminates)function. It never returns to its caller.

Answer (score 9):

I see there are many answers posted here that will fall into lucky cases to get the job done, but none of them are 100% deterministic to crash. Some will crash on one hardware and OS, the others would not.
However, there is a standard way as per official C++ standard to make it crash.

Quoting from [C++ Standard ***ISO/IEC 14882 §15.1-7***](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> If the exception handling mechanism, after completing the
>   initialization of the exception object but before the activation of a
>   handler for the exception, calls a function that exits via an
>   exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1).
>
> ```
> struct C {
>     C() { }
>     C(const C&) {
>         if (std::uncaught_exceptions()) {
>             throw 0; // throw during copy to handler’s exception-declaration object (15.3)
>         }
>     }
> };
> int main() {
>     try {
>     throw C(); // calls std::terminate() if construction of the handler’s
>     // exception-declaration object is not elided (12.8)
>     } catch(C) { }
> }
> ```

I have written a small code to demonstrate this and can be found and tried on [Ideone here](http://ideone.com/9UOOFa).

```
class MyClass{
    public:
    ~MyClass() throw(int) { throw 0;}
};

int main() {
  try {
    MyClass myobj; // its destructor will cause an exception

    // This is another exception along with exception due to destructor of myobj and will cause app to terminate
     throw 1;      // It could be some function call which can result in exception.
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout<<"Exception catched"<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

***ISO/IEC 14882 §15.1/9*** mentions throw without try block resulting in implicit call to abort:

> If no exception is presently being handled, executing a
>   throw-expression with no operand calls std::terminate()

Others include : 
throw from destructor: ***ISO/IEC 14882 §15.2/3***

Comment: **[`std::terminate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate)** works for me in a C++ application (so +1) but it might not be so simple if the application *does* have a non-default `std::terminate_handler` installed. The default one raises [`std::abort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) which *can* be handled and it isn't clear to me what will happen for a Windoze PC system then...

Answer (score 8):

```
*( ( char* ) NULL ) = 0;
```

This will produce a segmentation fault.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to crash.

Comment: "What will happen instead?" -- Anything could happen instead.  Behaviour is undefined, so the implementation could assign 0 to one of your program's variables, or it could assign 42 to one of your program's variables, or it could format your hard drive and continue executing your program.

Comment: (continuing "Windows programmer" set of mind) It can make you computer explode, or it may cause it to come a live and take over the humanity. or... it will crash in 99.9% and it's defined as "undefined behavior" because no one wants to take responsibility on it.

Comment: Actually, that's not guaranteed to even do undefined behaviour - it could completely defined and work properly. Consider this code: http://pastebin.com/WXCtTiDD (Tested on Linux as root, you could do this as a non-root user too if you do some config changes http://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr)

Comment: @cha0site: It is guaranteed to be undefined behavior by the Standard, because that is dereferencing a null pointer.  Whatever behavior you observed on Linux is allowable under the umbrella of "undefined behavior"

Comment: Different platforms can have different bahavior

Comment: This is undefined behavior and is not guaranteed to crash. Often compilers assume undefined behavior to be unreachable. In that case at least the crashing line is going to be deleted and other code might be as well.

Comment: It didn't crash on Irix. I sadly realized when we ported that code to Linux (where we even didn't reach `main()`).

Comment: Lots of microcontrollers have data at location 0 that you are meant to write.  Even the 6502 falls into this category.

Answer (score 7):

This one is missing:

```
int main = 42;
```

Comment: Yes it does; but it does something spectacular when you run it.

Answer (score 7):

This crashes on my Linux system, because string literals are stored in read only memory:

```
0[""]--;
```

By the way, g++ refuses to compile this. Compilers are getting smarter and smarter :)

Answer (score 6):

What about stack overflow by a dead loop recursive method call?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    StackOverflow(0);
}

void StackOverflow(int depth)
{
    char blockdata[10000];
    printf("Overflow: %d\n", depth);
    StackOverflow(depth+1);
}
```

See [Original example on Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315937)

Comment: What would prevent a Sufficiently Smart Compiler from optimizing away both the unused stack allocation and the tail call?

Comment: @JB: unfortunatly have no idea because not familar with existing compilers optimization logic

Comment: Well, compiled here with gcc 4.6.0 at optimization levels -O2 and above, it optimizes just fine.  It needs -O1 or lower to segfault.

Comment: @Abhinav: Just post your answer with all of these ways expressed as an examples in C++ :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a more guaranteed version of abort presented in above answers.It takes care of the situation when sigabrt is blocked.You can infact use any signal instead of abort that has the default action of crashing the program.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    sigset_t act;
    sigemptyset(&act);
    sigfillset(&act);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,&act,NULL);
    abort();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the snippet provided by Google in Breakpad.

```
  volatile int* a = reinterpret_cast<volatile int*>(NULL);
  *a = 1;
```

Comment: Since I'm testing Breakpad this is exactly what I wanted!  I found that some Breakpad minidumps don't produce a stack trace that points to the line in my code causing the crash.  This one does, so I can use it as good p.o.c. test.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 1 / 0;
```

Your compiler will probably warn you about this, but it compiles just fine under GCC 4.4.3
This will *probably* cause a SIGFPE (floating-point exception), which perhaps is not as likely in a real application as SIGSEGV (memory segmentation violation) as the other answers cause, but it's still a crash. In my opinion, this is much more readable.

Another way, if we're going to cheat and use `signal.h`, is:

```
#include <signal.h>
int main() {
    raise(SIGKILL);
}
```

This is guaranteed to kill the subprocess, to contrast with SIGSEGV.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to crash.

Comment: The C++ language does not guarantee that 1 / 0 will cause a SIGFPE. Behaviour is undefined. The implementation could say the result is 42.

Comment: Would this be a correct implementation? 42 is a well-defined number, it is not undefined.

Comment: Isn't that an integer division? Why should that result in a *floating-point* exception?

Comment: When behaviour is undefined, the implementation can do whatever it wants.  The C++ language neither prevents nor requires an implementation to write a crash dump, the C++ language neither prevents nor requires an implementation to assign 42, etc.

Comment: In my personal opinion SIGFPE is not the appropriate choice for division by zero, and it wasn't the best choice on a 16-bit machine where dividing -32768 by -1 didn't fit in a 16-bit signed int.  Intel didn't agree with me and a bunch of compiler developers don't agree with me.  Anyway, since behaviour is undefined, SIGFPE is equally allowable as assigning 42 or formatting hard drives.

Comment: @Windows programmer: The point is what undefined means. If I have a partial function f : A -> B, and f(a) is undefined for some a in A, then computing f(a) cannot return a value in B: either f(a) does not terminate or it returns some special value outside of B. Returning some random value b in B makes f(a) defined by f(a) = b, i.e. does not compute f as it was specified (f(a) MUST be undefined). So computing 1 / 0 cannot return a number because 1 / 0 is undefined on both integer and real numbers. IMO using undefined behaviour (i.e. anything will do) is not the correct approach here.

Comment: I think the correct approach to undefined is to either throw an exception or return a special value that indicates undefined (see e.g. the Maybe monad in Haskell). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#An_introductory_example_as_a_control_structure, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_functions

Comment: @Giorgio - the standard defines what the correct approach to handling things like this is and it's pretty clear - it's undefined behaviour, anything goes.

Comment: @awoodland: I am afraid you are correct. I can only hope that the C++ specification will be fixed with the next C++ revision.

Comment: @Giorgio - the C++ specification was written to be as flexible as possible. *Implementations* may therefore choose to throw an exception or set a flag to indicate invalid number. The standard deliberately avoids specifying what that should be though in order to avoid imposing large burdens on platforms which would, for example, have to wrap *every* division in order to do this.

Comment: @awoodland: Is checking if the second argument of x / y is zero a large burden? As far as I know checking if a register contains zero is one of the cheapest operations for a processor.

Comment: @Giorgio if the hardware doesn't have some way of trapping it automatically you still force compilers to emit at least two instructions, one of which would be a branch too. That's approximately doubling the cost of a division. Everybody pays that cost like that. If it's optional and you want it you can always use a library function for it still. If it's not optional and you don't want it you'd still end up paying the cost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5805/discussion-between-giorgio-and-awoodland)

Comment: For anyone googling later, Wikipedia informs me that SIGFPE is raised for backwards compatibility. AFAIK, there is no 'appropriate' signal for division by zero on POSIX platforms - `SIGFPE` is probably the closest. If one uses `signal()` calls properly - that is, setting a hander immediately before code that might cause a signal, and then resetting the signal handler to `SIG_DFL` immediately after those statements execute - the signal type isn't too important. If you're working with integers and you get a SIGFPE, it's pretty obvious what happened.

Comment: @AlexWebr: Please do not quote wikipedia as an authoritative source. Sure it is good for looking things up but follow the reference to the real source. Even wikipedia says do not use them as an authoritative source.

Comment: @Giorgio: I have an application that does a 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 * 10^1000000 divisions. I know for a fact that 0 of these will be a division by zero though there is no way the compiler can know this. **I definitely do not want** the compiler to plant the check for a division by zero.

Comment: @Loki Astari: if this creates a real performance problem you could perform your divisions using inline assembly. Furthermore, the compiler would only need to plant this check on a processor that does not trap division by zero itself which, to my knowledge, is quite rare. Anyway, I understand the C++ policy of not checking division by zero, pointers, array indices for performance reasons.

Comment: @Giorgio: Why should I pay for the cost just because you need/want it. Better to have no check and when I need it I will explicitly plant the check. The language designers made a choice. They opted for no checking so that we could have optimal speed as the default (Hence the operator[] and at()) The other choice would be to slow the code for everybody just so the incompetent/learners developers did so safely. I think they made the correct choice. I can write good safe/fast code without automated checks, I will explicitly add the checks when I need them thus only slowing my code when necessary.

Comment: This is undefined behavior and is not guaranteed to crash. Often compilers assume undefined behavior to be unreachable. In that case at least the crashing line is going to be deleted and other code might be as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
int* p=0;
*p=0;
```

This should crash too. On Windows it crashes with AccessViolation and it should do the same on all OS-es I guess.

Comment: `on all OS-es` No, it doesn't crash in non protected OS (e.g. MS-DOS.) Actually, sometimes there *is* something in address 0! For x86 real mode, Interrupt Vector Table is in address 0.

Comment: It didn't crash on Irix. I sadly realized when we ported that code to Linux (where we even didn't reach `main()`.

Comment: Lots of microcontrollers have data at location 0 that you are meant to write. Even the 6502 falls into this category.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question already has an accepted answer...

```
void main(){
    throw 1;
}
```

Or... `void main(){throw 1;}`

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buf=NULL;buf[0]=0;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing to a read-only memory will cause segmentation fault unless your system don't support read-only memory blocks.

```
int main() {
    (int&)main = 0;
}
```

I have tested it with MingGW 5.3.0 on Windows 7 and GCC on Linux Mint. I suppose that other compilers and systems will give a similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

Or another way since we're on the band wagon.

A lovely piece of infinite recursion. Guaranteed to blow your stack.

```
int main(int argv, char* argc)
{
   return main(argv, argc)
}
```

Prints out:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Calling `main` yourself is actually undefined behavior, in case you didn't know :) Also, tail recursion is *not* guaranteed to blow your stack. If you want a "guarantee", you have to do *something* after the recursive call, otherwise the compiler could optimize the recursion into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{

  int *aNumber = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  int j = 10;
  for(int i = 2; i <= j; ++i)
  {
      aNumber = (int*) realloc(aNumber, sizeof(int) * i);
      j += 10;
  }

}
```

Hope this crashes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int *p=3;
    int s;
    while(1) {
        s=*p;
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great to have some clarification :)

Comment: the p pointer will go beyond the program's address space which will be a memory error, as a process cannot access another process's memory. This will result the program to crash. pointer p is pointing to a random location in its address space, if it is incremented and dereferenced infinitely at some point it will point to another program's(process) address space. so it will crash after some time.

Comment: Or, hypothetically it could achieve integer overflow and wrap around, running infinitely. I'd try to use `long long` or `size_t` and start with `p` at the respective maximum value, or close to it, to crash faster. Though it's still not guaranteed to crash even in that case.

Answer (score 0):

A stylish way of doing this is a pure virtual function call:

```
class Base;

void func(Base*);

class Base
{
public:
   virtual void f() = 0;
   Base() 
   {
       func(this);
   }
};

class Derived : Base
{
   virtual void f()
   {
   }
};

void func(Base* p)
{
   p->f();
}


int main()
{
    Derived  d;
}
```

Compiled with gcc, this prints:

> pure virtual method called
>
> terminate called without an active exception
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

You can use of assembly in your c++ `code` ***BUT*** `INT 3` is only for x86 systems other systems may have other trap/breakpoint instructions.

```
int main()
{
    __asm int 3;

    return 0;
}
```

`INT 3` causes an interrupt and calls an interrupt vector set up by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use __builtin_trap() in GCC or clang, or __debugbreak() in MSVC. Not handling these breakpoints/traps will lead to an unhandled breakpoint exception/crash.
Other suggestions that use abort() or exit(): those may be handled by other threads, making it more difficult to see the stack of the thread that propagated the crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <thread>

void intentionalCrash()
{
    auto noop = [](){return;};
    // Thread t1 is in a joinable state.
    // When program returns t1 will be out of scope.
    // Destructing a joinable thread creates a crash.
    std::thread t1(noop);
}

int main()
{
    intentionalCrash();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple buffer overflow code that will cause the program to crash

```
int main()
{
    int n[0];
    n[2] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way considering the least number of characters is:

```
++*(int*)0;
```

This way it is not necessary to add any includes, just the code above.

Answer (score -2):

```
char*freeThis;
free(freeThis);
```

Freeing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. On many platforms/compilers, `freeThis` will have a random value (whatever was at that memory location before). Freeing it will ask the system to free the memory at that address, which will usually cause a segmentation fault and make the program crash.

Comment: This should always crash on all systems. `int *p = (int *)-1; *p = 1;`. This is because memory address 2^64 - 1 does not exist on any system, at least, not now (assuming pointer is 8 bytes long).