# Easy way to crash VB.NET Program

Tags: vb.net, crash, abort

I have a program up and going that interacts with hardware, but I need to test the case of when the program crashes/aborts or anything to cause the program to exit unnormally to see what state is set to the hardware when the software crashes.

In C++ I saw a post about using an `abort()` call ([What is the easiest way to make a C++ program crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481783/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-make-a-c-program-crash)), but I am unsure what the VB equivalent of that would be. The closest I have come is while debugging, to press the Stop Debugging button, but I think there is a better solution than that.

Is there any specific code that would cause this type of event to happen or is there a call like `abort()` that would make it happen in a heartbeat?

Comment: No idea if this is relevant to your situation but you might also want to look at the Application Events UnhandledException handler - you could maybe use this as a backstop to respond to (nearly) any exception and force the hardware into a known safe state.

Answer (score 6):

Use the API `Environment.FailFast`.  This is a .Net API accessible from any managed language including VB.Net.  It will ruthlessly terminate the current process

- [Environment::FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx)