# What does "*((char*)-1) = 'x';" code mean?

Tags: c, redis, undefined-behavior

I had a problem in reading redis source code, can anyone tell me what is the use of the last statement in the `_redisAssert` function in *debug.c*:

```
*((char*)-1) = 'x';
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to cause a seg-fault...

Comment: Seems to be there to assure a segmentation fault/bus error.

Comment: would be nice to have the full _redisAssert code for context.

Comment: A discussion on the validity of `((void *) -1)` as address here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13306914/694576

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

I found the line in [debug.c](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/debug.c#L384) mentioned in the OP and we can see from two lines above this code:

```
redisLog(REDIS_WARNING,"(forcing SIGSEGV to print the bug report.)");
```

and the same code can be found in `_redisPanic` as well, so it looks like their way to force a `SIGSEGV` when an assertion fails or there is a panic.

**Original**

This looks like a debugging tool, we can see from this document [Redis debugging guide](http://redis.io/topics/debugging) and relevant section says:

> Redis has a command to simulate a segmentation fault (in other words a bad crash) using the DEBUG SEGFAULT command (don't use it against a real production instance of course ;). So I'll use this command to crash my instance to show what happens in the GDB side:

and shows this gdb output:

```
 (gdb) continue
 Continuing.

 Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
 Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0xffffffffffffffff
 debugCommand (c=0x7ffc32005000) at debug.c:220
 220         *((char*)-1) = 'x';
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What it is doing is casting `-1` to a *char ** and then performing indirection on it and assigning `'x'` to that memory location. As the thread that alk linked [Is ((void *) -1) a valid address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306914/is-void-1-a-valid-address) says on most systems it will not be valid to access, let alone assign a value to. This will generate a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) on most modern operating systems.

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and as was went over in the thread [What is the simplest standard conform way to produce a Segfault in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986351/what-is-the-simplest-standard-conform-way-to-produce-a-segfault-in-c/18986406#18986406) it can not be relied on. Compilers are getting smarter and there are some famous examples where the [compiler is smart about exploiting undefined behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/970) in unexpected and bad ways.

Answer (score 0):

In your expression `*((char*)-1) = 'x';`:

You're casting the value `-1` to `char *` which gives you a pointer to a negative address then your trying to assigne the value `'x'` to the content of this address which absolutly gives 
a segmentation fault.