# What signal is generated from *(int *)0='X';

Tags: c

What exactly does the following do (or try to do) in C?

```
*(int *)0='X';
```

And what signal would be generated? Would it be a SIGSEGV?

Comment: Yes, on most POSIX systems you'll get a SIGSEGV. P.S. -- any particular reason you couldn't compile this, and test it yourself?

Comment: To generate signals you must generate them explicitly. Undefined behavior is not reliable for that.

Comment: Perhaps related to [What does “*((char*)-1) = 'x';” code mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20844863/1708801)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik maybe he was forced to use losedows for a while?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Testing is not a suitable way to get definite answers about what the C language specifies. Undefined behaviour has the annoying habit of allowing anything to happen.

Comment: I would load the reset vector with an int representation of the character 'W'.  Nothing else would happen, (on my embedded board).

Comment: @chux - my hardware is broken - I designed it :)

Comment: @Martin James I see - the result is hardXare dependent.  At least you didn't type "chuw". ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of `*(int *)0='X';` is *undefined*.

The compiler is free to do anything it pleases. (i) raise a SIGSEGV, (ii) not compiling the line at all are two possibilities.

To generate a fault explicitly, use `raise` as appropriate (defined in `<signal.h>`).

Answer (score 0):

Putting this into a complete program, segv.c:

```
int
main(
    void)
{
    *(int *) 0 = 'X';
    return 0;
}
```

and compiling:

```
clang -Oz -Wno-error -s -o segv segv.c
```

Now, when I run it on my 64-bit GNU/Linux system, I do in fact get a segmentation fault:

```
fish: "./segv" terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

However, if you are seeking to generate segmentation faults, as some people in comments have pointed out, you should use `raise(3)` from `signal.h`.