# How can i make "stack oveflow" exception on x64

Tags: c++

I tried to make a "Stack overflow" exception.

This code throws an exception on x64 Debug.

```
void DumpSystem::makeStackOverflow()
{
    static int callCount = 0;
    ++callCount;
    makeStackOverflow();
}
```

But, This code don't throws an exception on x64 Release
The x64 Release xxx.exe was LOOP without causing a "Stack Overflow" exception.

Build Option : "SEH(/EHa)"

I want to create a "Dump File" using "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter".

This is the code I used

```
LONG saveDumpfile(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ex);

unsigned __stdcall saveDumpFileForStackOverflow(void* arg)
{
    EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ex = static_cast<EXCEPTION_POINTERS*>(arg);
    return saveDumpfile(ex);
}

LONG exceptionHandling(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ex)
{

    if (ex &&
        ex->ExceptionRecord &&
        ex->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW)
    {

        HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0,
            saveDumpFileForStackOverflow, ex, NULL, NULL);
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    }

    return saveDumpfile(ex);
}

void registrationDumpSystem()
{
    ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(exceptionHandling);
}

LONG saveDumpfile(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ex)
{
    if (ex == NULL)
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;

    LONG result = EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;

    //%APPDATA% : C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming
    wstring filePath = getAppDataFolderPath();


    SHCreateDirectoryEx(NULL, filePath.c_str(), NULL);


    filePath.append(TEXT("\\Dump.dmp"));
    HANDLE file = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(),
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD lerr = GetLastError();
        return lerr;
    }

    HANDLE processHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
    DWORD processId = GetCurrentProcessId();

    MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION mei;
    mei.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    mei.ExceptionPointers = ex;
    mei.ClientPointers = false;

    MiniDumpWriteDump(processHandle, processId, file,
        MiniDumpNormal, &mei, NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(file);

    return result;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{
    registrationDumpSystem();
    //to do
    return 0;
}
```

"x64 Debug exe" it is work. 
so i can make "dump.dmp" file.

but, "x64 release exe" is't work.
i can't make "dump.dmp" file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRhWM.jpg)
I want to know why the program does not exit on x64 release.

please, could you tell me this reason?

Comment: The compiler probably did tail call optimisation, effectively turning your recursive function into a loop. Try adding a meaningful statement after the recursive function call.

Comment: @Max Please don't provide technical responses/answers in the comments section. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do I do if I'm not sure and don't have the time to investigate/confirm but want to leave a pointer for others?

Comment: I will use more complex code. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Max: Nothing. You don't _have_ to write something. But by dumping it here you stole our ability to peer review your contribution. Since by your own admission you weren't sure it was actually accurate, that's double un-good. If you're not sure what the answer is you can just leave it for someone who is. (Similarly, if you don't have time, leave it for someone who does.)

Answer (score 0):

You're making a common mistake, which is to think of your C++ source code as a one-to-one mapping of human instructions to machine instructions. It isn't. It's *a description of a program*. The process of converting this description into an actual program that the computer can execute is very complicated; naively we say that modern compilers "optimize" the code, but that's really a backwards way to look at it.

In fact, the compiler will try to create a program that does what you wanted it to do, producing the best code possible given those constraints (or slightly worse code, if you asked for a "low optimisation level", resulting in code that more closely matches your source and thus permits more convenient debugging). In this case, you simply asked to perform the behaviour of that function (which is effectively *nothing*) repeatedly and infinitely.

Now, *if* the code were directly converted into a recursive sequence of jumps and whatnot, you'd end up with a stack overflow because you'd run out of stack space for all the function contexts.

But! "[Tail call optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)" exists. This is a thing that compilers can do, in certain circumstances, to produce something more resembling a *loop* than a nest of recursive calls. In the resulting code, there is no infinite stack required and thus no exception.

As explored above, dropping optimisation levels down (which is what a debug build tends to involve), will result in "worse" code more closely matching the specific source that you wrote, and it seems that you are seeing the effect of this in your debug build: an actual recursion is produced even though it doesn't need to be. Since the recursion is infinite, your program crashes.

Comment: oh!! "Tail call"
Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void DumpSystem::makeStackOverflow()
{
    static int callCount = 0;
    ++callCount;
    makeStackOverflow();
}
```

Can be optimized to something like

```
void DumpSystem::makeStackOverflow()
{
    static int callCount = 0;
    while (true) ++callCount;
}
```

with [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) and if that is what your compiler is doing then you will never get a stack overflow.  You wouldn't see that in debug mode because debug mode normally does no optimizations.

If you want to force a crash there are many ways presented in: [What is the easiest way to make a C++ program crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481783/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-make-a-c-program-crash)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will use more complex code.