# int main = 0, is compiled but crashed

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I had very simple program as below.

`int main = 0;`

This program as `a.c` file compiled fine with `gcc-4.8`,`gcc-5`,`gcc-6`,`gcc-7` and `gcc-8` and application crashed when executed.

Same program as `a.cpp` file compiled fine with `g++-4.8` and `g++-5` and application crashed when executed. But with later version of g++ it gives compile time error.

Below is my questions.

1. Why a.cpp compile fine with g++-4.8 and 5, but not with later one? Does it bug in previous version of g++ OR some improvement in c++ standard?
2. If it compile successfully then why application get crashed?

Below is details compiler and output of compilation/execution.

```
+ gcc-4.8 --version
gcc-4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ gcc-4.8 c.c
+ ./a.out
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
+ gcc-5 --version
gcc-5 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ gcc-5 c.c
+ ./a.out
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
+ gcc-6 --version
gcc-6 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ gcc-6 c.c
+ ./a.out
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
+ gcc-7 --version
gcc-7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ gcc-7 c.c
+ ./a.out
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
+ gcc-8 --version
gcc-8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ gcc-8 c.c
+ ./a.out
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
+ g++-4.8 --version
g++-4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ g++-4.8 c.cpp
+ ./a.out
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
+ g++-5 --version
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ g++-5 c.cpp
+ ./a.out
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
+ g++-6 --version
g++-6 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ g++-6 c.cpp
c.cpp:1:5: error: cannot declare ‘::main’ to be a global variable
 int main = 0;
     ^~~~
+ g++-7 --version
g++-7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ g++-7 c.cpp
c.cpp:1:5: error: cannot declare ‘::main’ to be a global variable
 int main = 0;
     ^~~~
+ g++-8 --version
g++-8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

+ g++-8 c.cpp
c.cpp:1:5: error: cannot declare ‘::main’ to be a global variable
 int main = 0;
     ^~~~
```

Note: I already come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321937/4635560) but I doesn't answer my questions. 
Let me know if I need to add any specific tag to get attention of person with knowledge of this particular problem.

Comment: `int main = 0;` should not compile live: https://godbolt.org/z/uh3nm6

Comment: @RichardCritten I didn't say it is compiling every time. Check version details of compiler I mention on question.

Comment: @RichardCritten And It is not for clang. It is for gcc.

Comment: _"...the name main in the global namespace is reserved for functions..."_: source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: If you're using the name `main` for a variable, you're doing it wrong. It's undefined behaviour. Don't waste your time investigating why it compiles on certain compiles and not on others and why it segfaults

Comment: @RichardCritten this question is less about standard and more about compiler and behavior

Comment: @ManthanTilva if you really want to find out what happens, look at the [generated assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/TqvSVm). No code is actually generated and the code that will be executed is whatever junk is in memory.

Comment: Undefined behavior is behavior that is undefined. It's like tossing down a bottle from a skyscraper, then afterwards go down on the street to see what damage it caused, if any. During some circumstances it was crash into cars, in some cases it will hit a pedestrian, in other cases nobody gets hurts. Who cares why, stop throwing bottles. Just because the owner of the skyscraper has not banned you from using the elevator, it doesn't mean that they take any responsibility for you throwing bottles nor will they ensure that your bottles fly in some deterministic manner. The skyscraper is just fine.

Comment: Famous mechanisms at work: garbage in garbage out...

Comment: @RichardCritten compile as **`C`** not C++

Comment: @P__J__  Am following the [C++] tag and not the [C] tag; also OP say `g++` so I missed the `C` part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A program with such a declaration

```
int main = 0;
```

in the global namespace (or file scope in C) is ill-formed.

More modern compilers can issue a compile-time  error.

From the C++ 17 Standard (6.6.1 main function)

> 3. … A program that declares a variable main at global scope or that declares the
>      name main with C language linkage (in any namespace) is
>      ill-formed. The name main is not otherwise reserved.

You might use such a declaration in a C++ program for example the following way

```
namespace Name
{
    int main = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Part of the explanation for changes between compilers is that the constraints on `main` have changed between C++ standards.

C++98 (section 3.6 para 3) says

> The function `main` shall not be used (3.2) within a program. The linkage (3.5) of `main` is implementation-defined. A program that declares `main` to be `inline` or `static` is ill-formed. The name main is not otherwise reserved.

C++11 says essentially the same thing - except it removes the reference to Section 3.2 and also disallows `main` being `constexpr`  (consistent with the fact that C++11 introduced `constexpr`).

From this, I would suggest that - before C++11 - compiler implementers had plenty of freedom about what to do if code defined a variable at file scope named `main`.   Practically, I'm inclined to further suggest they may not have thought about that particular case at all but - if queried on a program compiling and crashing - they could probably make a claim of undefined behaviour.   One type of undefined behaviour occurs when the standard simply doesn't constrain what happens.

C++17, moves the discussion of the `main` function to Section 6.6.1.   In para 3 of that section it says  (bold highlighting mine, of text that was not in an earlier standard)

> The function `main` shall not be used within a program. The linkage (6.5) of `main` is implementation-defined. A program that defines `main` as deleted or that declares `main` to be `inline`, `static`, or `constexpr` is ill-formed.  The `main` function shall not be declared with a linkage-specification (10.5). **A program that declares a variable
>   `main` at global scope or that declares the name main with C language linkage (in any namespace) is ill-formed.**   The name `main` is not otherwise reserved.

From C++17, defining a variable at file scope named `main` at file scope therefore makes a program ill-formed - which then means an implementation may diagnose an error.

Answer (score 1):

For **C**, using `main` as a variable is undefined and can be caught through syntax, so all compilers should diagnose this. C17 says

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>   ... etc

and then come the two possible prototypes for `main` as a function.

The **shall** here is important, it makes it explicitly undefined to use the identifier `main` differently.

Answer (score 1):

There are two slightly different questions here:

1. Why is `int main = 0;` wrong?
2. If `int main = 0;` is wrong, why do different compilers treat it differently?

Before answering either question, it's worth making an oft-repeated analogy: A Programming Standard (like that for C or C++) is a lot like a *contract* between you, the programmer, and the programmers who wrote the compiler you're using.  If you follow all the rules in the contract when you write your program, and if the compiler writers followed all the rules when they wrote your compiler, everything should work fine.  But if any rules get broken on either side, things go wrong.

Now, most of the rules in a programming language contract are sort of conditional: *If you want to add two numbers, the operator you use is `+`.*  You don't get to decide you want to use the keyword `add`; the language says you use the symbol `+`, and that's that.

Some of the rules in a programming language contract are absolute, and negative, in that they tell you what you must not do.  *You must not add a pointer and a floating-point value.*

But there are a very few rules — I can really only think of one — that are absolute and *positive*, in that they tell you what you *must* do, whether you want to or not.  The one rule I can think of concerns the *entry point* of your program.  You must have an entry point function, its main must be `main`, its return value must be `int`, and it must accept either zero parameters, or two: one of type `int` and one of type `char **`.  (You do get to pick your own names for those parameters, although it's conventional to name them `argc` and `argv`.)

So when you wrote

```
int main = 0;
```

you broke that rule, albeit in an unusual way: you *did* have something named `main`, but it was an integer, not a function.

If this is still perplexing to you, consider this example.  Suppose you write a file `main.c` containing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int f();

int main()
{
    printf("About to call function f() ...\n");
    f();
    printf("back from function f().\n");
}
```

You've got a very simple `main` function, calling a function `f` which is presumably defined in a separate source file.  And suppose you do create that separate source file, `f.c`, containing

```
char f[] = "Hello, world!";
```

Obviously there's a pretty gross mismatch here between how you externally *declared* `f` in `main.c`, and how you actually *defined* it in `f.c`.

But if you compile `main.c` and `f.c` using a C compiler, and link the resulting object files together with a conventional linker, it's likely to give no errors.  (I tried it just now, and got none.)  But it crashes when it runs, for the obvious reason.

The question of whether a compiler might actually complain about the "gross mismatch" depends on a number of things.  Traditionally, C compilers were very generic about the code they compiled, meaning that no names were special.  If you declared something named `main` that's improperly an array instead of a function, typically the compiler wouldn't notice.  And by the time you're linking together separately-compiled object files, all the linker knows about (again, based on traditional object file formats) is that there's something at an address identified by the identifier `main`; the linker has no way of knowing the stuff at `main` isn't properly-compiled machine language code corresponding to a callable function.

More recently, compilers have begun making use of the guarantees afforded them by the Standard, and "learning" abut Standard-imposed identifiers, including `main`.  And indeed two different modern compilers I tried complained "variable named 'main' with external linkage has undefined behavior".

And when it comes to C++, things get more complicated still.  Typically, the linker does *not* just know that "there's something at an address identified by an identifier", typically there's extra information (if only via "mangled names") by which the linker *can* tell the difference between an identifier identifying a blob of memory containing some data, versus an identifier identifying a blob of memory containing some compiled machine instructions.